# AdMob - You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges

Tags: xamarin, admob

I am trying to get admob to work in my **Xamarin Android** application but I get the following message when trying to display an add:

**"You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges"**

I ave added the Xamarin google play service to my application.
I am set the java heap size to 1G and build with API level 14

I have googled the error message and most answerspoint to the manifest file that needs to include two entries. I have added the entries but still have the problem.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Here is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="Aftermath">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think soon it will be recommended to use the official AdMob Ads plugin for unity from Google. Well I use it and is easy to setup. Cross-platform as well. Here is the link :- https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins

Comment: Hi Kunalxigxag and thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I'll give this a bash and update.